# Selenium web driver gets timed out when switching to the parent window after closing the modal dialog window in IE 11

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have web page when I click on a link it opens a modal dialog (Dialog A) and when I click on a button in 'Dialog A' it opens another modal dialog (Dialog B) after doing some operation on 'Dialog B' I'm saving and closing the 'Dialog B' to switch to 'Dialog A' this is where I'm getting the below web driver exception. 'Dialog B' is getting closed successfully issue is occurring when switching to 'Dialog A'.

Below is the exception that I'm getting:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was caught
HResult=-2146233088
Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL   http://localhost:7067/session/4f24fcad-a867-4b0d-bf97-ab409b97ec67/window timed out after 60 seconds.
Source=WebDriver
StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTargetLocator.Window(String windowName)
InnerException: System.Net.WebException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=The operation has timed out
   Source=System
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   InnerException:
```

I have tried closing the modal dialog window using below methods and tried switching to its parent but still no luck.

- Closing the modal dialog by clicking on the close button and try
  switching to parent window – NOT WORKED
- Executing the Java Script of the close button and try switching to
  parent window – NOT WORKED
- Closing the modal dialog using “window.close()” and try switching to
  parent window – NOT WORKED
- Closing the modal dialog using IWebDriver.Close() method and try
  switching to parent window – NOT WORKED

I'm using Selenium web driver v2.48

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I switched to modal dialog 'Dialog A' and used IWebDriver.Close() method to close that modal dialog which closed the modal dialog 'Dialog B' as well (since Dialog A is the parent for Dialog B). By doing this web driver doesn't timed out when switching to the main web page.